# Xvfb with -nocursor shows cursor anyway

Tags: xorg, xvfb

I'm using `xvfb-run` to execute Xvfb:

```
xvfb-run \
  --server-num 44 \
  -s "-nocursor -ac -screen 0 1280x720x24" \
  chromium-browser \
    --temp-profile \
    --window-size=1280,720 \
    --disable-gpu \
    --window-position=0,0 \
    --app=http://example.com
```

If I then look at the process list, I see the expected Xvfb process and parameters:

```
Xvfb :44 -nocursor -ac -screen 0 1280x720x24 -nolisten tcp -auth /tmp/xvfb-run.3QqQAT/Xauthority
```

Despite that `-nocursor` is there, the cursor definitely still shows up if I use something like FFmpeg's x11grab to see the output of that window.

[image: Cursor is still visible in X11 window]

Even unloading the `psmouse` module doesn't fix this.

What's the proper way to specify that the cursor should be completely hidden?

Ubuntu 16.04 Server.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It turns out that I just need to specify `-draw_mouse 0` on the FFmpeg command line.  A good friend of mine tells me that x11grab sits at one layer below the Xvfb stuff, so that while the cursor isn't drawn on the frame buffer, x11grab will draw it.

Comment: Note that `-draw_mouse 0` is an _input_ option, so it has to go before the `-i` argument, otherwise it won't work.